# Solve the following inequality. $\frac{x+2}{x+3}\geq1, x \neq-3$

Tags: inequality

Solve the following inequality.
$\frac{x+2}{x+3}\geq1, x \neq-3$

My attempt:
$\frac{x+2}{x+3}\geq1 \implies \frac{x+2}{x+3}-1\geq0 \implies
\frac{x+2-x-3}{x+3} \geq0 \implies \frac{-1}{x+3} \geq0\implies \frac{1}{x+3} \leq0  \implies \frac{1}{x+3} < 0$,

Comment: In the solution, I saw $\frac{1}{x+3} < 0 \implies x+3 <0 \implies x < -3$ but I couldn't understand it.

Comment: Multiply both sides of the inequation by $(x+3)^2$, which is a positive number and won't affect the inequality sign.

Comment: 1. Do you agree that $x+3\geq0$ implies that $\displaystyle\frac{1}{x+3}$ is either positive or undefined? Since the consequent is false, then the hypothesis too must be false.  2. Continuing from the given solution in the '$\implies$' style of your working: $x<-3\implies x^2>9\implies x<-3 \,\text{ or }\, x>3.$ All steps have been valid, yet this new solution is incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fraction $\dfrac{A}{B} $ is negative $\iff$ $[A>0 \ \mathrm{and} \ B<0] \ \mathrm{or} \ [A<0 \ \mathrm{and} \ B>0]$.

Now, the problem is  $\Bigg[ \dfrac{1}{x+3}$ is negative. $\Bigg]$.

For $\dfrac{1}{x+3}$, the numerator $1$ is positive so it follows that the denominator $x+3$ has to be negative.

Answer (score 0):

After your last step, you need to write $x+3\lt0$ because only then the overall expression will be negative.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the function
$$f(x)=\frac{x+2}{x+3}-1=\frac{-1}{x+3}.$$
It may only change sign at its zeroes or where it's not defined, i.e., at $x=-3$.